# Using query values outside a function

Tags: php, variables, pdo

i need to use a "question" variable outside the function:

```
public  function name(){
    if($_SESSION[agT] == "random" AND $_SESSION[ct]=="random"){
    $consult = DB::getConn()->prepare('SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
    $consult->execute();
    $question=$consult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Like

```
echo "$question[column];
echo "$question[anothercolumn];
```

Comment: Well, [time to learn functions then](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)

Comment: Time to learn basic programming techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others stated, you should learn the basics of procedural and functions programming. You can just return the value of the query from the function :

```
public  function_name(){
    if($_SESSION[agT] == "random" AND $_SESSION[ct]=="random"){
    $consult = DB::getConn()->prepare('SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
    $consult->execute();
    $question=$consult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $question
}

$result = function_name();

echo $question['col1'];
echo $question['col2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

do 
`return $question`

then call this function

`$val = name();`